# Blender Scaling, Sizes

Tags: units

Im trying to design a piece for a mechanism in Blender, its x and y coordinates size should be equal. The z coordinate(height) should be a little higher. The size which is getting shown in my measurments is different.
[image]
The Scale is corresponding to the shown lenghts and heights, 1.6 and 1.2. But why does it say in dimensions that X is different than y when they clearly are equally big. I actually have the image selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between scale and dimensions:

[image]